# Why does my iPod display "Artist Unknown" after I entered in the artists in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch

I had a bunch of songs on iTunes that didn't have artist names, so consequently, I didn't have artist names on my iPod touch. I added artist names to all the songs I have on iTunes and now the artist names are not even showing up on my iPod. It just says "Artist Unknown" I really have no idea what to do. Can someone help me?

Comment: I assume you did sync your iPod after changing the names in iTunes. Are you using iTunes Match?

Comment: Yes i did sync it after changing the names...and I'm using iTunes 10, not match

Comment: This is making me mad >:(

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue after upgrading my iPod touch to iOS 5.1.1. I ended up restoring it to factory settings, and setting to auto-sync with iTunes (I ordinarily prefer to sync it manually!). I also had to change not only all "artist" names but also "album artist" names, as the new software appears to list the music according to album artists.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same weird problem. After you download a music or something, be sure to check if the file is "read only" in properties. just uncheck it, make you changes on the file (album artwork, composers, album name etc.).